# Can't return to Main PROC from a recursive loop - Stack Overflow

Tags: loops, assembly, recursion, masm, irvine32

I'm trying to program a simple loop that calls itself and keeps track of how many times it loops.  When I step through it, once `ECX` hits 0 inside `recursive PROC`, it jumps to `RET` inside `L1` - I thought after 0 it would return to `main PROC`

My understanding is that when a procedure is called it pushes the instruction pointer on the stack and then when the `RET` is called it pops it off and goes back to that point.

```
; Calls a recursive procedure
;

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data

constant DWORD 5
count DWORD ?

.code
main PROC
    mov eax, 0
    mov ecx, constant
    CALL recursive
main ENDP

recursive PROC
    add eax, 1
    loop L1
    ret
    L1:
        CALL recursive
        ret
recursive ENDP

END main
```

When I take `RET` out of `L1` I get "No source code available" page that comes up in Visual S 2013.

Comment: To get back to `main` you'll have to execute as many `RET`s as you've made `CALL`s. What happens if you continue stepping?

Answer (score 0):

If I print the value of `eax` in `main` right after `CALL recursive` I get `5`, so your code *does* get back to `main`. The problem is that your `main` is missing a `ret`. That  is, it should be changed to:

```
main PROC
    mov eax, 0
    mov ecx, constant
    CALL recursive
    ret
main ENDP
```

Since that's where your program is supposed to end you could also use the Win32 function `invoke ExitProcess,0` instead of `ret`.

Answer (score -1):

The issue with your initial answer is that after recursively calling your function, the return address has been buried by pushes onto the stack by the recursive function. Every time a call is performed, the return address of the encompassing procedure is pushed onto the stack and ESP is decremented. If we keep calling a function recursively without returning from it, the stack contains all of those duplicate addresses and ESP points to the last call.

You will need to pop all those recursive functions calls from the stacks in order for the ret instruction to be valid. You can verify this behaviour using a debugger:

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096

includelib  Irvine32.lib
includelib  User32.lib
include     Irvine32.inc

.code
main PROC
    mov eax,0
    mov ecx,5               ; # calls to perform
    call    recurs
    call    WriteInt

    INVOKE ExitProcess,0

main ENDP

; input   - ecx, parameter for  # function calls to perform
; uses ebx as workspace to dump junk from the stack 
recurs  PROC 
    loop    L1
    mov     ecx,eax     ; we need to keep track of recursive call count. 
L2: pop     ebx
    loop    L2
    inc     eax         ; add 1 for the initial call to made to recurs     
    ret                 ; ret pops the address currently pointed to by
L1: inc     eax         ; by ESP into EIP.         
    call    recurs      
recurs  ENDP            

END main
```

Comment: If you just want to do ECX pop operations, `lea esp, [esp + ecx*4]` instead of doing `pop` in a loop.  That's not real recursion, though; you're basically optimizing it back into a loop but still using `call` instead of `jmp`.  It's not really recursion unless you `ret` back through that stack of return addresses with `ret`, not `pop`.  (Structured programming, not a `longjmp` back out of all those scopes in one step.)

Comment: Also, the fact that you have to hard-code the recursion depth that main passes *into* the recursive function totally invalidates this approach: it only works for one assemble-time-constant input value.  If you had a wrapper function that saved the initial arg somewhere for later use, that could be considered valid.  Also, your version of the function *doesn't* push anything on function entry, only `call` pushing a return address, so I don't think `RECR_COUNT*2` is correct; that would be too many pops.

Comment: I do have to say this is a clever abuse of `loop`-forward and `call` to make something part way between recursion and looping that sort of works.  And with a `ret` at the end of the function so that `call    recurs` can actually return without falling off the end, the forward `loop` jump could actually be used as a decrement and base-case check in a properly recursive function.

Comment: Thanks Peter, yes I had made a mistake with RECR_COUNT * 2, i had a uses directive trying to save register state, since removed.

Comment: Ok, that works now, but it's still not recursion.  Popping a return address off the stack without returning to it doesn't count.  You're incrementing EAX to track recursion depth (while ECX counts down towards the base case), but then instead of returning through the recursion you run a silly loop instead of `lea esp, [esp + eax*4}` to discard instead of using the return addresses.  This is like taking an exception or doing a `longjmp` to escape from multiple levels of nested function calls, sort of like a GOTO back into a parent scope.